# strtotime in php not giving exact time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, strtotime

I want to compare time from db with current time. strtotime for storing time in db is working fine. but when i use strtotime to get current time it is not giving me exact time. i checked that from an online website. here is my code:

This part store time in db:

```
public function Add($data)
{
    foreach ($data['check'] as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value['in'] as $k => $v) {

            if(!empty($value['in'][$k])) {
                $allocate = array(
                    'check_in' => strtotime(date('h:i A', strtotime($value['in'][$k]))),
                    'check_out' =>strtotime(date('h:i A', strtotime($value['out'][$k]))),
                    //'check_in' => strtotime($value['in'][$k]),
                    //'check_out' =>strtotime($value['out'][$k]),
                    'Days_id' => $key,
                    'User_id' => $data['Users']
                );

                $this->db->insert('assgin_days',$allocate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This part compare time from db with current time:

```
public function checkuserlogin()
{
    $string = exec('getmac');
    $mac = substr($string, 0, 17); 
    $day_of_week = date('N');
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");
    $time = strtotime(date('h:i A'));
    $timee = date('h:i A');
    $id=$this->user_model->userInfo("id");
    $data=$this->db->query("SELECT admin.first_name, days.d_name FROM assgin_days INNER JOIN admin ON admin.id= assgin_days.User_id inner join days ON days.D_id= assgin_days.Days_id where assgin_days.User_id = $id and assgin_days.Days_id =$day_of_week and assgin_days.check_in =<$time and assgin_days.check_out >=$time and assgin_days.is_delete=0")->result_array();
}
```

Comment: check database server and php server timezone

Comment: *when i use strtotime to get current time it is not giving me exact time.* That is true. It's UNIX time so it's rounded to the closest integer.

Comment: *it is not giving me exact time*. And what **does** it give you? Please edit your question so it contains [mcve], we don't need your whole program.

Comment: What does "exact time" mean to you?

Comment: "store time in db....strtotime(date('h:i A', strtotime($value['in'][$k])))" - OMG WTF! You are not storing accurate times. You are not using the right structures in your PHP code for processing times. In all likelihood you are not using the appropriate stuctures in your database for storing/processing times.

Comment: Before any queries, but after you use date_default_timezone_set(): `$this->db->query('SET time_zone = "' . date('P') . '"');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use  date('G:i', strtotime($value['in'][$k])), instead of date('H:i', strtotime($value['in'][$k])), it will change the date into 24 hrs formats then it can easily store and comparable.

```
 public function Add($data){

    foreach ($data['check'] as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value['in'] as $k => $v) {

    if(!empty($value['in'][$k]))
    {
    $allocate = array(
    'check_in' => date('G:i', strtotime($value['in'][$k])),
    'check_out' =>date('G:i', strtotime($value['out'][$k])),
    'Days_id' => $key,
    'User_id' => $data['Users']);

    $this->db->insert('assgin_days',$allocate);
    }
    }
    }
  }
```